# How do I disable IntelliSense for Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-mac, disable, user-preferences, word-completion

I've tried following online instructions, but even though everything is unchecked and I save the changes, I am still getting word completion suggestions from IntelliSense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try this: open the Visual Studio Mac IDE. Then click on the Visual Studio menu and select Preferences. In the Preferences window, select Text Editor > C# > General. Uncheck the checkbox for "Automatic Completion" to disable IntelliSense.

Comment: I can't do exactly what you're saying.  Under Preferences > Text Editor > General I've unchecked everything.  Under Preferences > Behaviour > C# I've unchecked everything.  And also under Preferences > IntelliSense I've unchecked everything.  These I've already tried btw.

Comment: How about Preferences > Intellisense > Uncheck "Show completion list after a character is typed"?

Comment: Yep.  Tried that too.  It shows as being unchecked, but it's as if it is still checked.